# Executing webform from proxied page

Tags: curl, webforms

Hullo,
I would like to extract a number of links been triggered upon selecting the options of a webform. In order to test the behavior of it I copied the html of the page to my server and tried submitted the form but the correct link was not generated. I also tried adding a  command but it went even worse. How may I pretend to be submitting a webform like I were on the original web server?
The page is:
http://www.atm.it/it/Giromilano/Pagine/default.aspx
and my copy is at:
http://www.miafoto.it/iPhone/inarrivo/phpMi/form.html
the form to be submitted giving very different results is the second one with buses and trams.

Thanks

Comment: The question you ask is unlcear. Whease edit your text above and try to make clean what you actually have, try to get and show your attempts and scripts so far.

Comment: I do not know how to make it much clearer. The latter page is an exact duplicate of the source of the former. Yet submitting the above mentioned form in the two pages gives way to very different results. I wondered why and if there is a fix.

Comment: What do you mean by "links getting triggered"? what does "tried adding a commadn" mean? A web form "on the original server" does not make sense, forms are displayed and used by clients, not servers. And most of all: what _are_ the differences in the result? Post the results!

Comment: If I knew I would be much better off. When I select an option on the form on the official page an URL is opened that seems not to be present in the page. When I copy the page and execute it on my server a totally different URL is called. In particular my page opens a not working URL http://www.atm-mi.it/it/Search/default.aspx?s=ATM while the page on the website the correct URL: http://www.atm.it/it/Giromilano/Pagine/default.aspx?lvid=e5cc02af-2e68-40bb-98fc657db4c5f27d-50a2c293&wbt=nav&contextname=e5cc02af-2e68-40bb-98fc657db4c5f27d-50a2c293&vp=524&lst=1&lsi=3

Comment: Lets try to sort that out a little further: when you say you 'copy' that page to your server, you are talking about that html page currently open? and that you then server that statical html you copied? Well, a web application/portal/cms/whatever consists not only of statical pages but some more ingredients. You cannot expect a single rendered static page to be usable when taken out of its normal situation. IN your case for example the page appears to redirect to a seach form because the 'normal' target the page would call does not exist. And the search engine is also missing on your server...

Comment: One thought: but you are not talking about the way 'your copy' looks like compared to the original page? I mean when I compare the two links you posted inside your question it is obvious that the style sheets are missing and probably also some script and images...

Comment: As a matter of fact the two pages are more intermingled than I thought: saving the generated url and using it later takes nowhere. What I need to do is to trigger that selection and parse the generated page on the fly, or else saving something that allows me to generate the page myself at a later time: the url was no good. I found some information about triggering a form by curl but nothing about webforms. How may I do it without copying the page to my server, given that operation is meaningless, as you also said? the selection is the one with heading 'Cerca linee e orari' in the official site

Comment: Sorry, you still did not make clear what it is that is happening and what you want to do. You mentioned many details and asumptions, many terms, but I have the impression that you don't really know what you actually want to do. Sort that out. And I mean a precise reply, not something like I 'might have to' and 'somehow' and 'triggering'. You have to original page. What is it you want to get/retrieve/reach?

Comment: Ok, I try to be as clear as possible. That page presents a listbox and a button clicking which an apparently unrelated page opens. I would need to select an arbitrary element in the selection and click the button in a php program to have a web page back to parse. Sorry for my English but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Ok, now things become clearer. In my words: you want to do the same 'as if' using a browser and clicking the button, but from a php script which analyses the page returned to scratch some information from it. Ok. You need to analyse the logic how the 'target url' is created. That logic is contained insdie the page you see, mostly javascript functions. But most likely that is not all information required. Usually there is a session tracked on serer side where information about the client is stored, something like a 'situation'. You cannot retrieve that information.

Comment: I suggest you use some developer console inside a browser: the 'firebug' extendion for firefox, some other browsers bring something along preinstalled. Usually invoked with pressing F12 inside the browser window. This allows to select the 'submit' button you mention. Looking at its markup you see that upon pressing a js function is called. You can attach the js debugger inside the console you are using to that function (it is part of the page) and follow step by step what it does. This is not a trivial thing to do, but you can learn that. And such knowledge is valuable for the future!

Comment: It beats me how it is not possible to replicate what a human does by a php-curl program. Yet, given this is no trivial issue and I am a iOS and php programmer and no web guru, I have offered the work on peopleforhour.com for euro 100. And of course I would be happy to extend this offer here, if someone is interested.

Comment: Certainly php is capable of doing all steps required. The problem is to find those steps. It might be an interesting approach to use a headless browser capable of javascript (has to be standards conform...) and to 'simulate' a human click instead of traing to understand the logic actually taking place. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but in the meantime is someone willing to take the challenge and help me before a submit to a guy in Islamabad that has pledged to solve my problems, but of whom I know nothing about?

Comment: Anyway I submitted the work to the guy in Islamabad, I will keep you posted about what comes out.

Comment: Who so far provided me as a feat a get_html call, let's see but if any of you wants to keep up the challenge I would be much more reassured.

Comment: At any rate I downloaded Firebug and tried to use your suggestions: yet I found no way to check what happens clicking the button by selecting it as you suggest. If I click the button the new page is loaded upfront and the script on the page are just executed when the information I need is shown - I put breakpoints quite everywhere and function WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is nowhere to be found in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the listboxes, but rather in a number of hidden paramters that were to be submitted along with the visible parameters: after cleaning the page chunk bu chunk I was left with just a number of values to be set and they actually worked.